# removeclass doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

i have a very simple question, actually this is not the question, this is fixing the javascript mistake, anyway, here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#accordion a.item').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            $('#accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('slow');  
        });
    });
```

and the html:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item">BANKS</a>
        <ul>BLA BLA BLA</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item">PETROL</a>
        <ul>BLA BLA BLA</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

when i click one of the link, the 'selected' class is added to it, but when i click the other link, the class 'selected' is not removing, what can be the mistake there?

thank you all for helping! i really appreciate it!

Comment: You are adding and removing the class on the same element. Is this a typo?

Comment: I don't see how the `selected` class can be added to either - your code adds then immediately removes the class from whatever anchor is clicked on.

Comment: Actually what are you doing, its like first you will add class selected to the clicked a tag then you are removing this class ..

Comment: thank you all guys, i know it )) just didnt know how to rewrite it to make it work ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do, but it looks like you want to add the class to the clicked element and *remove* it from the all its *siblings*. Your current code adds and removes the class to the same element, which ends up not doing anything.

You probably want something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $items = $('#accordion a.item'); // all the items
    $items.click(function () {
        $items.removeClass('selected'); // remove class from everything
        $(this).addClass('selected'); // add class to clicked item
        $('#accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('slow');  
    });
});
```

Comment: yes! exactly! it was my mistake, and ofcourse it ended up doing nothing :) i just didn't know exactly how to rewrite the code, thank you! as soon as 8 min will pass, i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`ToggeleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) rahter then `adClass/ removeClass` methos.

```
$("Selector").toggleClass('name of class',true); //apply class
$("Selector").toggleClass('name of class',false); //remove class
```

Comment: -1: Are you serious? The code is adding a class and then removing it from the same element. It's obviously not working.

Comment: @Jon - As per my understand he want to apply class and than want to remove a class from the element ...thats y I sugested this way...any ways I think I m on wrong way ...but toggleClass does make sense if you want to apply and remove the class..

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is the link you clicked, not all the link. You need to remove the class of all link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#accordion a.item').click(function () {
            $('#accordion a.item').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $('#accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('slow');  
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

These following lines in your functions are adding and removing class selected to the same element.

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
$(this).removeClass('selected');
```

since you are adding and removing class on the element referred to by **this** which is the current element( the one that was just clicked). What these will do is add the class selected to the clicked element and immediately remove it.

What you need to do is

1- first remove the class selected from any elements that have it

2- add the class selected to the current element referred by **this**

one way to do it is

```
$('#accordion a.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

hope that helps.