# All Pagination link comes active when page loads

Tags: javascript

My pagination is always loading with all pages active. 
I can't seem to drop the class="active" for the other pages, so right now user can't tell what page he is on.

```
    <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
        <ul id="pag">
            {% for res in pagecount.items %}
                <li class="active">
                      <a class="active" href="javascript:handler_next_page({{ res.1 }})">{{ res.0 }}</a>
                </li>
             {% endfor %}
          </ul>
     </div>
```

I tried to use this code but it takes all of them out ([removeclass doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990514/removeclass-doesnt-work))

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $items = $('#pag li.item'); // all the items
         $items.click(function () {
         $items.removeClass('selected'); // remove class from everything
         $(this).addClass('selected'); // add class to clicked item
         $('#pag li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
         $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('slow');  
         });
     });
```

I also tried this, with no success [Disabled link in Bootstrap Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019707/disabled-link-in-bootstrap-pagination)

```
    $('.pagination .disabled a, .pagination .active a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I know there are many examples of this, although if someone can give me a heads up on how to do this i"ll be thankful.

Comment: it's normal,your active class is inside a loop, so it will be repeated,add a condition

Comment: you are removing the "selected" class, is that a typo? why are you not removing the "active" class?

Comment: ...how do you know what is the current page?

Comment: I will try adding a condition, makes sense. @FaceOfJock

Comment: It was just a typo, actual code was with "active" @GorkenYurtseven

Comment: good point @gvee, I don't know